# Remove div after 10 seconds

Tags: jquery, html, animation

I have been doing a lot of research and was trying to find a way to delete my div. This is my personal website and I wanted to have a jquery text animation but after 10 seconds I want it to stop. I figured the best way to do this would be by deleting the div that is being animated. It seems like I have the pieces to make it work (a function and calling it), but it doesn't seem to work.

```js
function fadein() {
    var fade = document.getElementById('fade');
    fade.setAttribute("class", fade.getAttribute('class') + " loaded");
}
$(function() {
    var txt = $('#textlzr');
    txt.textualizer();
    txt.textualizer('start');
    setTimeout(stopText, 10000);
})

function stopText() {
    $("#textlzr").remove();
    console.log('I stopped!');
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onload="fadein()">
  <div id="fade">
    <div id="textlzr">
      <p> think outside the box </p>
      <p> </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Converted your code into a snippet. What is `txt.textualizer`? (you can click on the "Run code snippet" to see errors.

Comment: Please expand on your question. As @Dekekl mentions, where is the function `textualizer`? Also You're mixing jQuery and native javascript. Use jQuery since you are linking the API. ex: `var fade = $('#fade');`. I'll touch on that after you update your question.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code where the timeout works perfectly fine. Please note that the method you used the textualizer didn't work so I implemented another method for this. I am also destroying the textualizer instance with the line `$('#textlzr').textualizer('destroy');` then removing the element.

Unable to make the snippet work in SO Snippet tool, please use the below working JSFiddle as reference

[`JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/ge3mg86t/1/)

**Code:**

```
function fadein() {
  var fade = document.getElementById('fade');
  fade.setAttribute("class", fade.getAttribute('class') + " loaded");
}
$(function() {  
        var list = [ 'Think outside the box','Think inside the box'];
        var options = {
          duration: 1000,
          rearrangeDuration: 1000,
          effect: 'random',
          centered: true
        };
        var txt = $('#txtlzr');
        txt.textualizer(list, options); // textualize it!
        txt.textualizer('start'); // start
        setTimeout(stopText, 10000);
});
function stopText() {
  $('#txtlzr').textualizer('destroy');
  $("#txtlzr").remove();
  console.log('I stopped!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you have to set width and height for **div** what you will transform with [**textualizer**](http://krisk.github.io/textualizer/).

FYI Your code in snippet didn't work because you forgot to connect script of textualizer and you have to use https.

```js
function fadein() {
  $("#fade").attr("class",  $("#fade").attr('class') + " loaded");
}

$(function() {
  var txt = $('#textlzr'); 
  txt.textualizer();
  txt.textualizer('start');
  setTimeout(stopText, 10000);          
});

function stopText() {
  $("#textlzr").remove();
  console.log('I stopped!');
}
```

```css
#textlzr {
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://krisk.github.io/textualizer/assets/js/textualizer.min.js"></script> 
<body onload="fadein()">
  <div id="fade"> 
        <div id="textlzr">
          <p> think outside the box </p>
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
```